# flask's 2 different Variable Rules of URL Routing, what is the differences?

Tags: python, url, flask

I am designing a blog web app, and I want to add **comments** on it. And I do not know which way is better, for **action url** of comment form.

### Way 1

```
@app.route(/blog/<post_id>/comment/, methods=['POST'])
def comment(post_id):
    # add comment to db
    pass
```

### way 2

```
@app.route(/blog/comment/<post_id>/,methods=['POST'])
def comment(post_id):
    # add comment to db
    pass
```

#### P.S.

- `/blog/<post_id>/` is the permanent url for posts
- will there some conflicts when visit the post permanent url throught way1

Which one is legal? or which one is better? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are legal. Which is better depends on what you are doing, which you don't mention.

The latter suggests to me that it refers to a specific comment uniquely identified by an id, e.g. `/blog/comment/1234/` would mean comment with id `1234`.

However, I guess that your intention is to reference the `comment` *resource* (multiple comments) associated with a post given by an id.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I add more detail and make it more clear.